# SharePoint 2016 - I have code to open Calendar events into a modal popup window, but how would I tweak code to have the popup open in Edit by default?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, list, javascript, 2016

So I found the below code, from the below link, which allows SharePoint calendar events to be opened in a modal pop-up view rather than loaded into a new page, but would it be possible to tweak the code so that the pop-up opens into Edit mode by default so the user wouldn't have to manually click into Edit for the pop-up to make edits to the event? I am total noob with JavaScript and code in general.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/e3c3aa6b-fb12-47d7-a64d-9985bf6a41e5/sharepoint-2013-calendar-overlay-open-in-the-model-popup?forum=sharepointdevelopment

```
<script src=http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $("a[href*='DispForm.aspx']").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("onclick", "openDialog('" + $(this).text() + "','" + $(this).attr("href") + "')");
            $(this).attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
            $(this).removeAttr("target");
        });
    }, 900);
});

function openDialog(title, url) {
    var options = {
        title: "Calendar - " + title,

    autoSize:true,
        url: url
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to open the edit form in dialog:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $("a[href*='DispForm.aspx']").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("onclick", "openDialog('" + $(this).text() + "','" + $(this).attr("href").replace('DispForm.aspx', 'EditForm.aspx') + "')");
                $(this).attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
                $(this).removeAttr("target");
            });
        }, 900);
    });

    function openDialog(title, url) {
        var options = {
            title: "Calendar - " + title,

        autoSize:true,
            url: url
        };
        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  So the event opens directly into Edit mode, which is great!  But, I do get a Web Part Error within the edit window (see below link for image):  Web Part Error: Unknown server tag. Correlation ID: 0ce82ca0-477c-c013-39cb-500b5c84bafa.     https://ibb.co/0K7gQ2j

Comment: It is working fine at my end, I don't get any errors while using this code. Can you add the screenshot of error to your original question? Link in your above comment is not working.

Comment: Ahh, you know what? I am getting this Web Part Error even without adding your modified code. So your code definitely works well for me, I am just not sure why I am getting the Web Part Error.  I am getting the web part error after manually go into Edit mode WITHOUT your code.  So something is weird.  Would you try this link?      https://ibb.co/0K7gQ2j

Comment: I have marked your answer as the solution.  I still dont know why I have the Web Part Error while in Edit mode though.  As a bonus question, is there a way to tweak the code so that Saving an Edit to an event refreshes the webpart or sharepoint page?  It's weird to save a change and not see it reflected on the calendar.

Comment: Still not able to see the image using link given in above comments.